# Minified Javascript doesn't work when combined in one file

Tags: javascript, minify

I have 3 JS libraries that I use that are in their own separate files.  They are commented with the code minified in each individual file

```
file 1: http://jsfiddle.net/NGMVa/

file 2: http://jsfiddle.net/AzEME/

file 3: http://jsfiddle.net/qVkhn/
```

Now individually they work fine in my app, don't throw any errors.  But I wanted to load less files so I combined them into one file like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxswy/

However, in Chrome it throws an error on the last line of the file:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and it then it doesn't work anymore.  I didn't change anything in the code before I combined them, I just copy and pasted the content of the first 3 files into the new one, and it doesn't work anymore.  Don't understand why combining them into one file seems to break functionality

Was hoping someone would have an idea what's going here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to add the semicolons at the end of each file or concatenate and then minify and minifier should take care of that.

Try this code: https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/4728677

Comment: the individual files didn't have the semicolon, how come they worked in there? I guess since there is now more JS code then just that function definition it needs the semicolon to separate the 3 file contents

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

In my case it was because I specified dependencies in `requirejs`'s `shim`, for a library (`perfect-scrollbar`) that already supports AMD loading. The result is that the whole of its code in `define` is bypassed after `grunt-contrib-requirejs` did its job.

Basically, to concat requirejs files together, `grunt-contrib-requirejs` would

```
// change this:
define(['d3'],function(d3){...});

// into this:
define('d3', ['d3'],function(d3){...});
```

Whereas inside `perfect-scrollbar`, there's already

```
(function (factory) {
  'use strict';

  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.

    define(['jquery'], factory); // <-------------------------- this part
    // after minification would become:
    // define('PerfectScrollbar', ['jquery'], factory);

  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    factory(require('jquery')); // Node/CommonJS
  } else {
    factory(jQuery); // Browser globals
  }
}(function ($) {
  // perfect-scrollbar code here...
});
```

Which conflicted with what I specified in `shim`:

```
shim: {
    "PerfectScrollbar": ['jquery', 'jquery.mousewheel']
}
```

Therefore when `requirejs` got to the part where `PerfectScrollbar` was really defined, it hopped over it, assuming that it has already done the job.

### Solution

Don't specify dependencies in `shim` for libraries that already have AMD support.

### Question

But what if I need to specify dependencies? I need `jquery.mousewheel` on top of the `jquery` it already specified in its code.

### Answer

Require that file with proper require, and get its own dependencies right:

```
define(['perfect-scrollbar', 'jquery.mousewheel'], function(){...});
```

Either when the library you need has AMD support,

```
// inside jquery.mousewheel:
require(['jquery'], factory);
```

Or it doesn't

```
shim: {
    "IDontSupportAMD": ['jquery']
}
```